# Can't make customized option work when enforcing API-key based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, configuration, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API project that has no security enforced. Now I need to secure it with an API key based authentication scheme.

The basic idea is to let the clients of this Web API pass in an API key in a header, then all the client API keys will be held in the `appsettings.json` file.

These are the implementation details:

1. Setup a customized `ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions` where `MyConfigValue` will be used to hold the keys

```
    public class ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
        public const string DefaultScheme = "ApiKey";
        public string Scheme => DefaultScheme;
        public string AuthenticationType = DefaultScheme;
        public string MyConfigValue { get; set; }
    }
```

2. In startup, the authentication logic is added to service collection

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
            services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
         services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddApiKeyAuthentication(Configuration);
         services.AddControllers();
    }
```

3. The extension method of `AuthenticationBuilder` is defined as

```
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddApiKeyAuthentication(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var config = configuration["MyConfigValue"];
        builder.Services.Configure<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.MyConfigValue = config;
        });

        builder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, options => { });

        return builder;
    }
```

4. The authentication handler is defined as

```
    public class ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions>
    {
        private const string ApiKeyName = "X-Api-Key";

        public ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var myConfigValue = Options.MyConfigValue;

            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey(ApiKeyName))
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing API Key");
            }

            var apiKey = Request.Headers[ApiKeyName];

            if (apiKey != myConfigValue)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid API Key");
            }

            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "api-user") };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs here: The `options` in the `constructor` has a property `CurrentValue` that has the customized property `MyConfigValue` with the correct value from `appsettings`, however, in the function `HandleAuthenticateAsync`, the `Options` doesn't have a property of `CurrentValue`, but it has the customized property `MyConfigValue` that is null. Therefore, the `options` in the constructor is not the same as the `Options` in the function. My implementation of class `ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler` probably is wrong. One workaround now is to retrieve `MyConfigValue` inside the `constructor` and save it for use in the function.

5. Secure API calls by using:

   ```
   [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "ApiKey")]
   ```
6. I set `MyConfigValue` in the root level of `appsettings.json`.
   However, whenever the function `HandleAuthenticateAsync` is called triggered by secured API calls, `options.MyConfigValue` is always null.
   As soon as I use default `ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions` without `MyConfigValue` included, and then obtaining it inside `ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler`, then it works. But that requires obtaining `MyConfigValue` for each API call, not efficient.
   A simple solution in Visual Studio 2022 is available, I can provide it if asked. I will also try to figure out a way to upload to GitHub.

Can someone tell me what goes wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The `builder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, options => {  });`   reset the  ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions which caused your issue, why you don't directly set it like this `builder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, options => { options.MyConfigValue = configuration["MyConfigValue"];  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `builder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, options => {  });`   reset the  ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions which caused your issue.

You should directly use the `builder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, options => { options.MyConfigValue = configuration["MyConfigValue"];  });`

Details, like below:

```
public static class AuthenticationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddApiKeyAuthentication(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var config = configuration["MyConfigValue"];

        builder.AddScheme<ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions, ApiKeyAuthenticationHandler>(ApiKeyAuthenticationOptions.DefaultScheme, options => { options.MyConfigValue = configuration["MyConfigValue"];  });

        return builder;
    }
}
```